# VB - Using data held within a textbox to update a table

Tags: sql, vb.net, textbox

How do you use SQL to put data into an empty table? So far in my code I have taken the data from an SQL table and then have put it into a Text Box using the following code:

```
Dim query As String = "SELECT Pronunciation, Character FROM [Katakana List] WHERE Pronunciation='" & pronunciation & "';"
    Dim instruction = New SqlCommand(query, sqlCon)
    Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter
    da.SelectCommand = instruction
    da.Fill(Katakana)

Textbox1.text=DT.row(0)("column")
```

Now that the data is held in the text box, how would I do the reverse of this process to put the data into an empty table. It would help if someone could give me an example of the query I could use to put the data back in.

Comment: you want to save data to table on database , or but it back in datatable ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to set the data in the textbox into datatable just do it like this :

```
DT.row(0)("column") = Textbox1.text
```

if you want to enter it into database create query to do so , something like this :

```
Dim query As String = "Insert Into TableName(col1) Values('"& Textbox1.text &"');"
Dim command = New SqlCommand(query, sqlCon)
command.ExecuteNonQuery()
```

Comment: Sorry, but `Values(Textbox1.text)` will not work. `Textbox1.text` not variable for sql - just a string

Comment: Sorry, again, but now yuor query is vulnerable for [SQL Injection](http://www.unixwiz.net/techtips/sql-injection.html)

Answer (score 1):

If you want update data which you get from query before, then use `UPDATE`-query
If you want insert brand new data then use `INSERT` - query

```vb
'For updating existing data
Dim query As String = "UPDATE [Katakana List] SET Character = @NewCharacter WHERE Pronunciation=@Pronunciation"
'For Inserting new data
Dim query As String = "INSERT INTO [Katakana List] (Character) VALUES (@NewCharacter);" 
Using instruction As New SqlCommand(query, sqlCon)
    'Better practice to use parameters in query
    instruction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Pronunciation", pronunciation)
    instruction.Parameters.AddWithValue("@NewCharacter", Textbox1.text)
    instruction.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```